# Orthogonal basis from corresponding points in different unknown basis

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: diagram of corresponding points from different basis]

I have measurements of two points from different unknown basis (A and B). All I know is that the point in A correspondings to the point in B (by corresponds I mean they originate from the same point in the orthogonal basis). Is it possible to uncover the orthogonal basis from corresponding points alone?

Edit: the points in A and B are measured with respect to the orthogonal basis.